# Setting request headers

Tags: javascript, header

Хотел узнать можно ли составить заголовок таким образом как 1 , или же надо писать 2 заголовка как во 2-ром примере ?

```
1. xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json;text/plain");
===================================================================
2. xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Comment: Если у тебя содержимое переменного типа -ставь либо одил либо другой заголовок по ситуации. Но это не хорошо в рамках запроса на 1 URL . Два сразу - так не делается, и парсится такое только кривыми сервачками)

Comment: Вроде как оба бессмысленны, не?

Comment: О каком смысле ты говоришь не понимаю ? 
Почему оба бес бессмысленны??

Comment: А как одно содержимое может быть двух разных типов?

Comment: Мда... 
А почему одно содержимое не может быть разных типов ?

Comment: А это по-вашему как? Я такого содержимого пока не встречал за десять лет программирования.

Comment: Для запроса определённого типа в ответе сервера используется заголовок `Accept` — и вот в нём указать несколько типов как раз можно. Заголовок `Content-Type` используется для указания типа данных, которые отправляет сам клиент (или сервер, если этот заголовок присутствует в ответе сервера), а один кусок данных ну никак не может иметь несколько типов :)

Comment: ок спасибо. Тут и было недопонимание!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще-то, думаю, оба нельзя... Как у одного содержимого может быть несколько типов одновременно?